# Android layout background get compressed, if keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, background, keyboard

I am trying to write a code maintain the size of the layout even if Softkeyboard is visible. But the layout background image gets merged whenever keyboard is visble and layout looks cluttered. But  i have seen in whatsapp that , even if keyboard is open the background does not change it's state. So , i don't know the technique to do it.

**MyCode :**

```
package com.example.testlayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String[] data = new String[50];

ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.image_bgswitch);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        data[i] = "";
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, data);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} }
```

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.testlayout.MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

</ListView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10" />
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testlayout"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Screenshots :** 
**Keyboard not visible**
 [image]

[image]

**Keyboard is visible**

These are the above codes and screenshots of my issue , please suggest me the technique to keep background as it is even if keyboard is visible.

Answer (score 2):

Change `android:windowSoftInputMode` from `adjustResize` to `adjustPan` in your manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testlayout"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but adjustPan will hide the actionbar , i want the actionbar to be remain in the screen , whenever keyboard is visible. Please suggest me the technique

Comment: issue solved by adding getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.image_bgswitch); this and removing the layout background in the layout

Answer (score 2):

Change `android:windowSoftInputMode` from `adjustResize` to `adjustNothing` in your manifest

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```